# Android Custom ListView Rows: Text Style not being applied

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, xamarin

Trying to create custom rows in my listview (to look like [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qN0VfmEGulY/TVYYhN0q4aI/AAAAAAAAAAk/UToSiCsxapA/s1600/CustomDataList-clipped.png)). I've created a custom row layout & derived adapter class. The data loads and shows fine, but the text is not using any format/style specified in my custom row .xml layout file. It's all just the default size/weight, etc.

Here's the custom row layout (listview_desc.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#222222">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dip" 
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:text="Description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:textSize="13dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my main layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_darkbg">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My adapter code (I'm using Xamarin, but I don't think that's the problem...)

```
public class ListViewFormAdapter : BaseAdapter<Form> 
{
    List<Form> mForms;
    Activity context;

    public ListViewFormAdapter(Activity context, List<Form> items)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.mForms = items;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override Form this[int position]
    {
        get { return mForms[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return mForms.Count; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = mForms[position];

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_desc, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.name).Text = item.Name;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.description).Text = item.Description;

        return view;
    }
}
```

And finally the main activity where I load and use the adapter:

```
public class HomeScreenActivity : Activity
    {
        List<Form> mForms;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Home);

            // Load all forms and populate the main menu
            mForms = Utils.FormLoader.LoadForms("Forms");

            ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
            listView.Adapter = new ListViewFormAdapter(this, mForms);
        }
    }
```

Sorry for all the code, maybe it'll help someone in the future... thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a warning. In some cases, the style issues are caused because the context used by the adapter to inflate views might be an application context. In this case, the theme applied explicitly to the activity wouldn't be used at all.http://debuggingisfun.blogspot.com/2014/06/android-style-not-being-applied-to.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the response guys. Turns out it was some problem with Git/Xamarin. I committed my sources at another machine, came home, synced up and all my formatting in the row layout xml were gone. Who knows... maybe a cached version was being used or something. I actually had to use the code posted on this page to get it to work (since it was lost), so maybe someone can use this as example code. It works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the problem, but you inflating the views incorrectly. it should be

`view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_desc, parent, false);`

instead of

`view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_desc, null);`

using the 3 parameter version of inflate

Answer (score 1):

What styles aren't showing correctly? I'm not sure what you're expecting or what you're seeing from the question. If it is to do with alignment, you should bear in mind that `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` is not valid in a `LinearLayout`